# How many packets lost is "affordable" in terms of stable network?

Tags: ip, ping

Recently I've been having some issues with my internet connection. My mom complained that internet stops working sometimes and it comes back after a while.

It didn't happen to me, but did see it happening on Wi-Fi.

Today I decided to ping 8.8.8.8 over and over via my direct cable connection, and analyze packages received / lost.

So the results are the following:

- 2945 packages sent
- Received 2935
- Lost 10

Are 10 packages "a lot"?

I understand the percentage is so small, just a 0.33%, however, I'm not really sure if this could cause troubles which could be perceived by user.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a wired connection? Meaning that your connection to your modem and from your modem to your ISP are both wired? If so, then even 0.33% packet loss seems high. I don't think that would be noticeable by itself (WiFi has loss rates higher than that a lot), but if you're seeing that on a wired connection, it might be indicative of larger problems.

Comment: You have no evidence that any packets were lost. For example, the machine at 8.8.8.8 could have received every packet you sent and responded to all but 10 of them, with you getting every single one of those responses.

Comment: @Ickster yes. Wired.